# Embedded JMS broker with http transport

Tags: java, servlets, websocket, jms, weblogic

I'm not exactly sure what I need and I hope that someone will have some idea how to solve my problem.

I have a huge legacy client(applet)-server(Weblogic) application which relies on JMS communication and due to some ongoing problems with firewalls I need to switch the async communication to http protocol(best would be to keep JMS interface so that I don't have to rewrite half of the application). I'm also very restricted in terms of what I can and cannot configure on the server and on the clients(i.e. installing new software is almost impossible). The best solution would involve modifications only in the code.

So my idea is this:

- Broker embedded in the current application(how? I know of activeMQ ajaxServlet, but I'm not sure how to send messages to that from java app)
- Some interface for clients which would comply with JMS 1.1 specification on one side and on the other side it would keep asynchronous connection with the ?servlet? on the server
- Messages don't need to be persisted.

Restrictions

- No installing/configuring of the server
- I cannot open new port for this communication
- open source

Is something like this possible? I know it's definitely not a best way to do that, but I'm very restricted.

Answer (score 1):

Kaazing (the company I work for) has a WebSocket gateway product that does pretty much everything you're looking for. A few points about your requirements:

- Kaazing implements the full JMS API on top of WebSocket and works with Apache ActiveMQ (and other JMS message brokers) - [see simple tutorial](http://tutorial.kaazing.com).
- Kaazing has sophisticated [WebSocket emulation](http://blog.kaazing.com/2011/11/17/the-industrys-best-websocket-emulation-real-time-web-apps-for-all-your-customers-even-if-theyre-on-ie6/) (in case native WebSocket support is not supported by the client). If doing the communication over HTTP, this may be an option for you (would be good to understand, though, why HTTP is such a key requirement for you).
- Kaazing allows you to completely close all the inbound ports on your firewall (see details on [Enterprise Shield](http://tech.kaazing.com/documentation/jms/3.5/reverse-connectivity/c_rc_whatis.html)).

Regarding your restrictions:
You are required to have a WebSocket server run in your architecture, and Kaazing is not open source.

If you're interested in more detail, feel free to reach out to me: peter dot moskovits at kaazing dot com.

Comment: Thanks. I've already read about Kaazing, but unfortunately commercial product is not suitable for me :( AFAIK, there is no OSS version.
Http protocol is not really a requirement. I'm just restricted in a way that I cannot open other sockets than what I already have.